# Embedded tomcat container is not taking the context path from application properties.(Spring boot)

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, spring-boot

I am using spring boot for my web application. I have set context path to `myApplication` in applciation properties.
But when I run my application, embedded container is not setting the context path.

**application.properties**

```
server.context-path=/myApplication
```

`o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/](Here the context is missing)`       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext (logs while running the container)

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: This works flawlessly for me. Can you share a [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your configuration

```
    @Component
    public class CustomizationBean implements  EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
     @Override
     public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) 
       {    
            container.setPort(8083);
       }
     }
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html